# Populating existing nav drawer in a new Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I searched for a case similar to my situation, but I couldn't find one that suited it. I have an Android Application with a Main Activity that includes a Navigation Drawer. The drawer options replace the container with different fragments. In one particular case, the use of Activities is more logical. Once I arrive in my new activity, my drawer is no longer existing, and my menu button to pull out this drawer transforms to a button with the standard "back" function. I would like to populate/extend/inherit/parent/send this drawer to my new Activity. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a BaseActivity Class which extends Activity. Add the code for the Navigation Drawer inside that activity.
2. Make sure that all other Activities extend the BaseActivity Class.
3. Add the navigation drawer xml to the xml layout of each activity.